# How to open form in same window of mvc3 view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

By using the following code,I able to open it in new window.but i want to open in same window or tab

```
@Html.ActionLink( "Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.studentID },new {target="_blank"})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new {target="_blank"}
```

Above code forces that form to be opened in new window. To force the form to open in the same window, you need to remove target = _blank.
So the updated code would look some what like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink( "Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.studentID }, null )
```

Comment: I was just going to post this.Hope this will help.giving target="_blank" makes to open the link in new tab.

Comment: i want to open the form like a popup in same window,but not open in same window replacing the main page...

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{target="_blank"}` to `{target="_self"}` , this URL replaces the current page.

**EDIT:** To open as a popup, specify the width and height of your choose.

```
@Html.ActionLink( "Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.studentID },null, new { @style= "width:100px; height:50px"})
```

Comment: i want to open the form like a popup in same window,but not open in same window replacing the main page...

Comment: I use twitter bootstrap modals for this very purpose. Perhaps if you look at how they implement those it will give you some direction